# Change values around in mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have the code below:

```
$do_id=$_GET['id'];
$new_workorder=$_GET['workorder'];

//get current workorder on file for record that will be updated
$query = "SELECT workorder FROM jvltodos WHERE id = '$do_id' LIMIT 1";
$bla = mysql_query($query);
$workorder_old = mysql_fetch_row($bla);

//get record for workorder on file that will have the new workorder
$query = "SELECT id FROM jvltodos WHERE workorder = '$new_workorder' LIMIT 1";
$bla = mysql_query($query);
$id_fix = mysql_fetch_row($bla);

if (isset($new_workorder) && $new_workorder!=$workorder_old) {
    //update the changed record
    $query = "UPDATE jvltodos
        SET workorder={$new_workorder}
        WHERE id = {$do_id}";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    //update the record that had the old workorder
    $query = "UPDATE jvltodos
        SET workorder={$workorder_old}
        WHERE id = {$id_fix}";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
}
```

I pass the 'id' and 'workorder' into the url, so I GET them first. With that I update the record with that 'id' to the new 'workorder'. So far so good.
But I want to find the record that has that 'workorder' and update that with the 'workorder' from the old 'id'. (In simple terms: when I increase/decrease the 'workorder', I want to switch two records around)
To me it looks pretty straightforward, but it doesn't work. The first thing (update the id with the new workorder works.. but the other record stays the same.. it keeps the workorder that was already in there)
What am I missing? (must be something simple that I'm just overlooking.)

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Have you tried echoing out the SQL you're generating to make sure it looks like you think it should?

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: @Fluffeh you know I'm going to refer you to http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23326/192634

Comment: @Matt try not to look at an Accept rate when answering, but I *know* that some folks will. Just pointing out the etiquette that is SO - it will probably help the chap (Note the second comment at +52 from a *mod* on the question you linked).

Comment: @Fluffeh I get it; that's why I didn't flag it as "off-topic"

Comment: @Fluffeh Sorry... I guess I'm an incredible n00b. I didn't know I had to click on the checkmark for the right answer; I always voted for the right one. Anyway, got that fixed now. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@andrewsi Thank you for the suggestion! I took the code out, copied it over to another page and did some echo's to see what was going on and that way I figured out easily what the problem was.

Example:
    $bla = mysql_query($query);
    $workorder_old = mysql_fetch_row($bla);

The $workorder_old that I wanted to have should've been a number. However, this didn't happen, but returned.. an array.
When I changed the code to...

```
$bla = mysql_query($query);
$bla = mysql_fetch_row($bla);
$workorder_old = $bla[0];
```

... it worked like a charm.

tiny note: I'm so used to grabbing the data in 1 step (another language), that I forgot that I needed to make a few steps in PHP. Guess it's time to throw it in a function perhaps.. :-)